# Passing values from aspx to php via an HTML-form and then storing them in a mysql database

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql

Is it possible for me to pass values to a php form using a aspx form and then storing that data in mysql database?

Comment: what do you call a "php form"?

Comment: @user1042031: nice... and how?

Comment: Poor question, if you had any experience writing and processing forms than you would know the answer to this, zero research effort

Answer (score 3):

From your ASPX form, set the action to your PHP page. From here, you can handle everything within your form via the PHP page you created.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a form with an action pointing at your php script, then when the user clicks submit it'll call your script:

```
<form method="POST" action="myPage.php">
```

Answer (score 2):

Forms (in this context) are neither PHP nor aspx - they are HTML.

If you want to make a POST request to a php file by using an asp server-side script then you will want to check cURL (or whatever the asp equivalent is).

Comment: wow, how did you know what user1512328 meant? :O cool! :)

Comment: @Chris - lol - I was just trying to guess. If one of my kids had asked me I'd have told him to phrase the question properly, but seeing as it's a public place, I try to be nice :)